# How can I get a job if I have a passive personality?

Tags: job-search, australia, applications

There's tips out there for Aggressive and Assertive people, but nothing for Passive. I used to have a job thanks to my dad but he changed companies and now I can't get my foot in anywhere. I've been looking for a new job ever since, and that was 9 months ago.

I have experience in an industry that wants qualifications, not experience, and I don't have the money to afford qualifications. (3 years).
I don't have connections beyond my father.
I apply for as many entry level positions as I can and quite often I either don't hear back, or I get an interview that fails.
I feel really bad about lying and I have next to no self confidence, so I assume my interviews fail because I'm not BSing my way to the job.

I'm not assertive. I'm not aggressive.
I am passive. I just want to work. I don't understand why this isn't good enough, but that's not the question, the question is how can I get a job in spite of my personality?

I'm not chasing high incomes or low effort careers. I'm just applying what I think I can do, and I keep getting denied. How am I supposed to get a job when I don't cheat and lie? When I don't chase and harass HR staff? When I don't guilt people into hiring? What do I do if I'm too passive?

Comment: Have you been getting many interviews?

Comment: Are you qualified for the jobs you are looking for? If you see a list of qualifications for a job do you have this qualifications and when you contact them do you show them that you have the qualifications?  If you think you have all the qualifications ask the people who don't want to hire you how you can improve. Like: What can I do that you hire me?

Comment: I get about an interview a week, but I went all of December without one.
I am only applying to jobs I can start immediately on and do, all of them are ones where I fit the qualifications and requirements of the position. Since I'm 19, I don't have much experience and it's mostly Entry Level.
I worked as a Sales Host / Draftee / Receptionist for 3 years, but Sales and Drafting work require education I don't have, and I keep getting denied for Receptionist roles.

Comment: Is there anything about you that looks old or unhealthy?  My offer-to-interview ratio improved drastically when I went to dying my hair (which was white in front at the time, and probably further back by now).

Comment: Lolx! And I deliberately don't dye mine, ***and*** wear a suit, for gravitas :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> so I assume my interviews fail because I'm not BSing my way to the job

This is probably an inaccurate assumption - BSing isn't required to get a job and is far from recommended in any case.

> How am I supposed to get a job when I don't cheat and lie?

By demonstrating that you are a good candidate - applying for jobs that you have the skills and experience for and telling the *truth* about the fact that you have said skills/experience.

> When I don't chase and harass HR staff?

Well harassing HR staff is generally counterproductive to getting hired anyway.

> When I don't guilt people into hiring?

Same as above.. there's no need to do this.

> I keep getting denied

You don't mention any numbers but it's not uncommon to get a *large* amount of rejections or non-responses during the job hunt. *Especially* if you aren't the typical candidate profile (such as you lacking the qualifications you mention) and that can mean you need to apply for a larger volume of positions than someone else, but that doesn't mean you should give up - remember that it doesn't matter how many "No"s you get, you just need that one "Yes".

> how can I get a job in spite of my personality?

If you know you aren't someone who can communicate your suitability for a role well in person then you'll need to work on other ways to get this across - make sure your CV is highly polished, really makes your experience and skills clear and easy to identify. Write a kick-ass cover letter.

And in addition work on your interviewing skills - you don't need to BS, you don't need to harass or guilt people. Just work on communicating honestly and clearly about your skills and experience. I appreciate that it's not easy - especially if you are of a shy persuasion and lacking in self confidence but it can be done and *any* small improvement will help. Do practice interviews, maybe join Toastmasters or similar if there is one in your area.